# Laravel custom error message from inside custom validator function using $validator->errors->add()

Tags: laravel, validation, custom-errors

I have custom validation rule `appointment_status`. I am performing various test cases on it and decide what error message is best and throwback. it will be different for every `case`. I want the `$validator->errors()->add('status', __('Invalid status for an appointment in past')` to set the error message and it's adding. but it's not returning back to the controller. I can't access this message anywhere. it shows only the `status.appointment_status` one which is set in `messages()` function.

Custom Request class:

```
namespace Modules\ShopManager\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AppointmentsRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        \Validator::extend('appointment_status', 'Modules\ShopManager\Validators\CustomValidator@appointmentStatus');

    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'services' => 'required',
            'sdate' => 'required|date_format:m-d-Y|time_range:sTime,edate,eTime,timezone',
            'edate' => 'required|date_format:m-d-Y|workinghours_range:sdate,sTime,edate,eTime,timezone',
            'sTime' => 'required|date_format:h:i a',
            'eTime' => 'required|date_format:h:i a',
            'cname' => 'required',
            'cphone' => 'required_without:cemail',
            'cemail' => 'nullable|required_without:cphone|email',
            'timezone' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required|appointment_status:sdate,sTime,edate,eTime,timezone',
        ];


        return $rules;

    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'status.appointment_status' => 'Invalid status'
        ];
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'services' => 'Services',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'sTime' => 'Start Time',
            'eTime' => 'End Time',
            'cname' => 'Customer name',
            'cphone' => 'Customer phone',
            'cemail' => 'Customer email',
            'internal_note' => 'Internal note',
            'status' => 'Status',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The custom validator function:

```
public function appointmentStatus($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $dateTimeOperations = new DateTimeOperations;

        $sdate = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0]);
        $startTime = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[1]);
        $edate = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[2]);
        $endTime = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[3]);
        $timezone = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[4]);

        $now = $dateTimeOperations->getNow($timezone);
        $start = $dateTimeOperations->getTimestamp($sdate, $startTime, $timezone);
        $end = $dateTimeOperations->getTimestamp($edate, $endTime, $timezone);

        switch ($value) {
            case constants('appointments.status.pendig'):
                $start->lessThan($now)
                ? $validator->errors()->add('status', __('Invalid status for an appointment in past'))                
                : '';
        }

        return $validator->errors()->any();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an error just to the field without specifying the rule I don't think will work, that's why the message from the validation request takes precedence.

So change it to this:

```
$validator->errors()->add('status.appointment_status', __('Invalid status for an appointment in past'))
```

And also in your case do you maybe have a typo: `pendig` to be `pending`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom validator rules and add below code inside your rule wherever required, See example below:

```
$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
    }
});
```